# Is there a free module or way to add discount on customer based?

Tags: magento-1.9

I know there is a way for the customer group in promotions but is their any way to assign promotions to individual customer based on attribute e.g customer user name, id or email e.t.c

Comment: Help me understand why you would want to do this?  Also - are you wanting to manually add this for an admin or you want to programatically detect say "if they have been a user for x amount of time - offer discount"?

Comment: Yes basically i want to assign discount to special customer based on their sales reputation manually through promotions, Its like if this user will buy more then $100 he will get 10 % discount